# When I set a specific date in the where close it works but when I change the year it doesn't work. Why?

Tags: sql

When I filter to 1/1/2020 in the where clause the query works. When I change the year to 2019 I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string

Why does it work for 1/1/2020 and not 1/1/2019? The matteropendate column is a date column -- I checked.

```
WITH aa (MatterNumber, claim_cat_NJS, ClaimCategoriesMulti) AS 
   (
    SELECT
      MatterNumber
      ,LEFT(ic.ClaimCategories, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), ic.ClaimCategories + CHAR(10) ) - 1)
      ,STUFF(ic.ClaimCategories, 1, CHARINDEX( CHAR(10) , ic.ClaimCategories + CHAR(10) ), '')
    FROM cases AS ic

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      aa.MatterNumber
      ,LEFT(aa.ClaimCategoriesMulti,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),aa.ClaimCategoriesMulti+CHAR(10)
      ,STUFF(aa.ClaimCategoriesMulti, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), aa.ClaimCategoriesMulti + CHAR(10)), '')
    FROM aa
    WHERE 1 = 1
      AND aa.ClaimCategoriesMulti > ''
    )
Select *

FROM cases AS c
LEFT JOIN aa ON c.matterNumber = aa.matterNumber

WHERE 1 = 1
  AND c.MatterOpenDate > '1/1/2019' /*this line of code results in error message whenever changed to a different year*/
```

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Show us your query.

Comment: You're showing us a query that doesn't appear to contain a date value at all. How do you think that helps us work out what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the format

```
WHERE DateField >= '2020-01-01'
```

Bear in mind the time component if its a DateTime

Comment: I tried putting it in that format, but it still doesn't work. It doesn't like the greater than or less than signs. If I use "=" it works.

Comment: Have you put them in the correct order - I'll update the example above to reflect >= not =>